# What is a non-word syllable?

Tags: meaning

I was looking for a list of commonly used syllables and came across this one which mentions that some of its syllables are "non-word syllables." I have no idea what this might mean and can't find a definition. I've found "non-words" but not "non-word *syllables."*

The term was used in an image [caption](https://medium.com/wugs/high-frequency-syllables-in-english-ab75159618a0).

> [image: 1 ðə 3.90% | 2 ə 3.17% | 3 ˈtu 2.10% | 4 ˈænd 1.90% | 5 ˈʌv 1.85% | 6 ɪn 1.82% | 7 [li] 0.96% | 8 ˈðæt 0.92% | 9 ˈaɪ 0.79% | 10 ˈfɔr 0.79% | etc.]
>   The 200 most frequent syllables in General American English, with non-word syllables highlighted.

Can anyone tell me what is meant by this phrase?

Comment: Can you cut and paste the sentence and some context from that link? The link is great but you want the text here too.

Comment: Alright. I'm not sure it'll be of much use in this case, unfortunately.

Comment: Lemma, for the convenience of visitors to this site because links rot and sometimes sites are behind paywalls. Both the link and the text are required here.

Comment: What is the confusion? In the word *paywall* there are two syllables but each syllable also exists as a word on its own. Neither of the two syllables in *prickle* exist as independent words, so these are *non-word* syllables.

Comment: @Mitch Oh I realize that, it's just that the source was just a caption and seemed to have too few contextual cues to be useful. Maybe it's more useful than I realize, though...

Comment: @Chappo The confusion was that I was unable to find a definition anywhere. And on top of that, I came up with interpretations that, as it turns out, weren't correct.
If you're curious, my initial interpretation was, "Syllables that are not found in _any_ word."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the table in the image at the link, it appears that **non-word syllables** are those syllables that do not, by themselves, constitute words, in contrast with **word syllables**, which are syllables that are also words.

From the linked article, here are some of the **word syllables**. These make the words "the," "a," "to/too/two," "and," "of," and "in":

[image]

Here are some of the highlighted **non-word syllables**. Note that, when pronounced standalone, do not sound like any English words, but are rather parts of words. These could be used in e.g. "gentle," "funnel," ..., "running," ...:

[image]